# Simple programming math

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to randomize objects in an object.

```
    do{
        e = enemyList[Math.floor(enemyList.length * Math.random())];
    } while (e.level > (player.level + 5) && e.level < (player.level - 5));
    return e;
```

How would I make it so "e" has to be between 5 levels above and 5 levels below in order for the loop to stop?

Yeah this is really easy, but my head hurts for some reason :p

Comment: How can it be both 5 levels above and 5 levels below at the same time?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, or give an example?  I don't know what you mean by 5 levels above AND 5 levels below. Also, it looks as though your function only returns one object (unless I'm reading it wrong), so why the loop?

Comment: I want the enemy level to be between the player's level minus 5 and plus 5. So the while statement should stop between 10 and 20 if you are level 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be using an `or` not an `and`. If it is 5 below OR if it is 5 above. Otherwise the condition will never be met.

Comment: Why? I want it to only be between -5 and +5

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression you wanted it to be above and below that. In this case, it seems like NPE's answer will do what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 No, this is actually the correct answer, given that the OP wants the loop to continue while `e` is out of range. The loop will exit once `e` is in range if the OP follows this answer.

Comment: Yeah this answer is correct. The and stops it sometimes, the or always works.

Answer (score 2):

You have the comparisons the wrong way round (`+` should be `-` and vice versa):

```
} while (e.level > (player.level - 5) && e.level < (player.level + 5));
```

(The wording of your question is somewhat ambiguous; it could be that you should be using `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`.)

Comment: What difference does the order make? Unless there are side effects, `&&` is commutative.

Comment: @Barmar: If you look carefully, the difference is more than the order (in fact, it has nothing to do with the order).

Comment: You've changed the sense -- you're testing whether `e` is _between_ 5 below and 5 above.

Comment: This will make it between 5 above and 5 below but I believe OP is asking how to make it 5 above or 5 below.

Comment: We really should wait until the poster clarifies the question before we try to answer. As written, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah this is right. Let me test it. 
Edit: Weird, I'm level 1 and it's ending the loop at 20 and continuing at 1.